# Is this proof correct - simple proof about distance in normed linear space

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, and let $M$ be a closed subset of $X$.
Show that any $x\in X\setminus M$ has non-zero distance from M.

My proof:

Assume there exists an $x\in X$ such that $\mathop{\mathrm{dist}}(x,M) = 0$ then $\inf_{y\in M} \|x-y\|=0$.

By non-degeneracy of the norm, $x-y=0$ and so $x=y$.

Since $x\in X\setminus M$ and $y\in M$ then $x=y\in M \cap X \setminus M = \emptyset$.

Contradiction.

The solution given is entirely different so I wonder if mine is correct (and presume it's not).

Comment: You have $\inf_{y\in M} \lvert\lvert x-y\rvert\rvert = 0$, but note that $\inf$ is different from $\min$. You don't necessarily have some $y\in M$ such that $\lvert \lvert x-y\rvert\rvert = 0$. However, you have a sequence of points of $M$ whose limit is $x$. You should be able to conclude with this!

Comment: Your proof is okay if $\dim X < \infty$. In general, $\inf \neq min$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is $y$ in the proof? Notice that a priori, "the infimum of $S$ is equal to $0$" does not mean that the infimum belongs to this set.

But using the definition of the infimum, for each $n$, there is $y_n\in F$ such that $\lVert x-y_n\rVert\leqslant n^{-1}$. This proves that $x\in \overline F$ and we conclude by closedness of $F$.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how the definition of the infimum translates to yours which uses sequences. Could you please explain a little?

Comment: The infimum of a bounded set $S$ is an element $m$ such that if $\delta$ is positive, then $m+\delta$ is not a below bound anymore. Here we take $\delta=n^{-1}$ for a fixed $n$.

Comment: So could we pick any other $\delta$ that converges to $0$?

Comment: Yes, we can play with $\delta$.

Comment: Okay thank you, makes sense now.